# maven - set the current project version

Tags: maven

I use mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=x.x.x to change the current project version. It only changes the version under element `"<version>"`. It does not change the version under element `"<properties>"` which has the dependent lib version. I am forced to do this manually every time.Is there anyway I can change all the versions in 1 step?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'under tag'?

Comment: Are you talking about a multi module build or do you mean particular dependencies ?

Comment: For some reason my question was not posted correctly. I will retype it again here... 

I use mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=x.x.x to change the current project version. It only changes the version under element "<version>". It does not change the version under element "<properties>" which has the dependent lib version. I am forced to do this manually every time.Is there anyway I can change all the versions in 1 step?

Comment: The versions plugin does not support updating the properties declared within your POM. You could alternatively attempt to override the property values on the commandline or alternatively stop using properties and use the versions plugin as it was designed to be used :-)

Comment: Which is simply wrong, cause it supports updating of properties (http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html).

Comment: @khmarbaise : Can you give me an example of how I can use update properties? Which parameter do I use to specify the old and new version? Thanks!

Comment: Just take a look into the docs: http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-property-updates.html and this one: http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-properties.html

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you're talking about.  Are you trying to bump the version number in the relevant dependency blocks as well?  I don't think there's a built-in way to do this, but here's an [xmlstar](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) one-liner that does for e.g. an entire groupId:

```
xmlstarlet ed -P -L -N p='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0' -u "/p:project/p:dependencies/p:dependency[p:groupId = 'my.group']/p:version" -v $VERSION $POM_FILE
```

I use this in a loop to batch set versions for many dependencies across many POMs.

Comment: Hi dacc, thanks for your reply. I tried installing xmlstarlet in my centos and not successful so far :-(. Very less documentation and help to get this started

Comment: That's weird.  Have no problem with just: sudo yum install xmlstarlet on CentOS 5.5.